# Remove synchronized azure active directory

Tags: azure, active-directory, synchronization, cloud, azure-active-directory

I have installed the Azure Active Directory sync Tool for testing purpose. All worked as expected and the Useraccounts are synced without errors.
Now after the testing phase I would like to remove all synced Users in the Azure Active Directory and then remove also the "connector" who syncs the AD informations.
When the whole directory is empty I will reinstall all on a new server and resync all with other settings.

So the question is:
- How can I reset or clear the Azure Active Directory?
- How can I remove the connector, so that I can deploy a new one?

Thanks

Comment: OK, when I remove every User step by step the Connector still will be there. So how can I remove the Connector?

Answer (score 0):

Presently there is no option for reset.You need to remove the users one by one.